# How to "invoke" PropertyInfo of type Action<,> in runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a generic class and a property of type `Action<,>`. I am wondering if there is a way to actually invoke this delegate using reflection in runtime, not just set value to this class property (via `PropertyInfo.SetValue`).

I tried a lot of things, like using expressions, dummy casting, read forums, but none of the solutions worked for me.

**Workaround:**
What I could think of is creating a dummy method which internally calls the delegate, and with reflection is fairly easy to invoke this method.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigData<T> 
    where T: class
{
    public Action<T, object> ValueInjector { get; set; }

    public void SetValue(T entity, object valueToSet)
    {
        this.ValueInjector(entity, valueToSet);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configObj = new ConfigData<Student>()
        {
            ValueInjector = (x, y) =>
            {
                // Some custom logic here
                x.Name = y.ToString();
            }
        };

        // Parameters
        Student student = new Student();
        object valueToSet = "Test";

        Type configType = configObj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = configType.GetProperty("ValueInjector");

        // Invoke the property info somehow with the parameters ?

        // Workarround - invoke a dummy method instead
        MethodInfo methodInfo = configType.GetMethod("SetValue");
        methodInfo.Invoke(configObj, new object[] { student, valueToSet });

        Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to invoke the `propertyInfo` variable and pass to it the two parameters I already have (`student, valueToSet`), since I know that it represent a delegate which can be run.

**Update:**
I tried with castings as suggested by @HimBromBeere.

```
//Error in runtime
var del = (Action)propertyInfo.GetValue(configObj, null);

//Error in runtime
var del = (Action<object, object>)propertyInfo.GetValue(configObj, null);

// Works but no generic
var del = (Action<Student, object>)propertyInfo.GetValue(configObj, null);
del.Invoke(student, valueToSet);
```

Only the last casting works and I am able to call `Invoke` on the delegate (no need of `DynamicInvoke`) and it works. However this is not a solution because I do not know the exact type to cast in runtime. I have it as variable T. Something like:

```
var del = (Action<T, object>)propertyInfo.GetValue(configObj, null);
```

So maybe if I manage to make a generic Type like this:

```
var d1 = typeof(Action<,>);
Type[] typeArgs = { propertyInfo.DeclaringType.GenericTypeArguments[0], typeof(object) };
Type delegateType = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
```

there might be a way to do this conversion and execute. Still wondering.

Comment: That last snippet with making the generic type is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the value returned from the property back to a delegate, e.g:

```
var del = (Action)propertyInfo.GetValue(configObj, null);
```

Now call the delegate with your params:

```
del.DynamicInvoke(student, valueToset)
```

Comment: If you cast to Action, then the Invoke method does not expect any parameters.

Comment: @antanta Indeed, the delegate isn´t strongly-typed, so it must be `DynamicInvoke`.